# Why Swing does not release focus on raw X Server

Tags: java, swing, focus, x11

I noticed that swing application behaves differently. I use Centos 6.5 and I start only raw X server without window manager. In this scenerio, keyboard focus depends on pointer posiotion. Window has keyboard focus if pointer is on it. I tested it on xterm, gnomer-terminal, gedit, firefox.

I developed very simple swing application:

```
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("JFrame tittle");
                JPanel p = new JPanel();

                JTextField textField = new JTextField("111111111111111");

                p.add(textField);
                jFrame.setContentPane(p);
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

If I run this application then `JTextField` has focus and I can't change focus to another window. When I move pointer on gnome-terminal `JTextField` has still keyboard focus and I can use keyboard only on it. I can open menu in gnome-terminal using pointer and menu has keyboard focus then (I can use arrow on menu) but when I close menu, focus returns to JTextField.

In short I can not use any another application. Why? What differs swing application from another? Why swing does not release focus when I move pointer on another window? **EDIT: I also clicked on another window of course.**

If I start window manager (`metacity`) then it works properly.

**=====EDIT====**
Picture 1 shows two window: xterm and gnome-terminal. When I move cursor on gnome-terminal then I can use keyboard to write in gnome-terminal, when I move cursor on xterm then keyboard writes to xterm. 
[image: Picture 1]

When I start my java swing application it appears in left top corner. I can only write into JTextField and cursor does not impact on keyboard focus.Following picture shows it:

[image]

I added printing of Look and Feel name and description to swing application so It is printed in console. It is irrelevant. 
[image]

**=====EDIT=====**

I found following quote int [this](http://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-x-window-managers-work-and-how-to-write-one-part-i.html) tutorial:

> Unlike citizens, the window manager has rights but not
>   responsibilities. Programs must be prepared to cooperate with any type
>   of window manager or with none at all […]. — Xlib Programming Manual
>   §1.2.3

So I think that Swing application should be prepared to work without WM.

Comment: i have problems to understand your problem. can you make screenshots? First, you say you don't use an WindowManager, then you say you can't click on another window. As far as i know, **the window manager** may choose the focused window based on cursor position. see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Comment: It is a bug in Swing (they seem to refer to it as "feature"). See e.g. [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/swing-dev/2010-June/001104.html) or [here](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6798064).

Comment: @n.m: keep in mind, Mariusz is not using **any** WindowManager. that means, the links you posted have nothing todo with his problem.

Comment: @Ben Swing breaks focus with "unsupported" window managers (which means that it's basically crap and its authors have no clue). Why should it play nice when ran with no window manager at all?

Comment: @n.m: i do not want to say that **without** windowmanager it should work. I just wonder, if the behaviour is really **wrong**, when **not using** any window-manager.

Comment: @Ben yes it is wrong. An application may degrade its own functionality if a supported WM isn't running, but it should not break other applications.

Comment: I agree that It should not break other application. I posted my question because it is very strange for me and I think that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As i already wrote in the comments, it may be a problem when **not using** a WindowManager.

see:

> There is no foolproof way, across all platforms, to ensure that a
>   window gains the focus. On some operating systems, such as Microsoft
>   Windows, the front window usually becomes the focused window. In these
>   cases, the Window.toFront method moves the window to the front,
>   thereby giving it the focus. However, on other operating systems, such
>   as Solaris™ Operating System, **the window manager** may choose the
>   focused window based on cursor position, and in these cases the
>   behavior of the Window.toFront method is different.

from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Comment: I am not expert in Xorg but I think that X server can manage focus without window manager. Keyboard focus depends on cursor position. But swing is exception. Swing has focus and Swing does not release it.  I asked also what swing has different form antoher application.